# PostgreSQL Store-and-Forrward

Tags: postgresql, store

I'm building a data collection RESTful API 0 External devices will post json data to database server. So, my idea is to make it by Store-and-Forward ideology.

1. At the moment of the post, it will store raw json data to table with timestamp and processed true/false fields.
2. At the next moment when(if) the db server is not loaded will run some function, trigger or stored procedure, etc. The idea is to process all json data into suitable tables and fields for charting graphs/bars and map it over Google Maps later.

So how and what to use to run this functionality(2) when the db server no loaded and free for processing the posted json data?

Comment: What kind of loads do you expect on your server?

Comment: Lets say average 2 posts per second with ~1kb of JSON data. Each post will produce 1-2 selects, 1-2 inserts and 1 update.

Comment: No, I mean the kind of load that would prevent immediate processing. How high is that, and when would it go down enough that you consider the server to be "*no loaded and free for processing*"?

Comment: Hmm....To be honest I'm just wondering to make it by this way....and simply  was thinking and looking for some solution....